# How convert sub dir to a submodule in git repo and commit it?

Tags: git, git-submodules

My project is already set and working. Some of the files are from an external project. Now, I want to use git to manage the changes of the external file from upstream.

I did the following:

```
rm <external files>              # <= should use "git rm"
git commit -m "prepare submodule"

git submodule add <...remote...> extLibs
cd extLibs
git pull master
<make changes>
git commit -m"make external project work with my project"

cd .. # back to upper level project
```

At this point, I found I have to commit changes in my main repo again for the files I have already committed in the submodule. **I don't even know if it is the correct behavior.** Can I change it so I don't need to commit twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only change you should see in your main repo is the gitlink ([special entry `160000`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)) referencing your git submodule folder should have changed (different SHA1).
You can add and commit that one change safely.

If you see more, that means your `git rm` didn't work as expected. (`git rm -r extLibs/` should have done the job)

Comment: Thanks @Vonc :) I forgot to use `git rm`.